# jQuery UI draggable resizable with Gridstack.JS - remove scrollbar and resize it 1 pixel at the time

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to implement a widget solution using GridstackJS ([link to gridstack](http://troolee.github.io/gridstack.js/))

If set the widget width = 8 and height = 2 and my widget has a lot of text, then the scroll bar will be shown to scroll up and down to see the widget content.

The scroll-bar is applied by the jQuery UI which Gridstack JS uses.

How can I remove that ugly scrollbar and replace it for example with Perfectscrollbar or make the widget height automatically based on the content height?

Here is a screenshot.

[image]

[image]

UPDATE:

I managed to remove the scrollbar by setting:

```
.grid-stack .grid-stack-item .grid-stack-item-content {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and then:

```
$('.grid-stack-item-content').perfectScrollbar();
```

Now the only problem is how to resize it one pixel at the time.

I think when you resize the widget, the next position if you expand it or shrink it will be:

- expand: whatever +  (`cell_height` + `vertical_margin`)
- shrink: whatever - (`cell_height` + `vertical_margin`)

Comment: What happens when you try using Perfectscrollbar?

Comment: I managed to fix the scrollbar issue and using perfectscrollbar instead. The main thing is about resizing the widget one pixel at the time for accuracy. Any ideas how to do that? BTW: Thank you for Gridstack.JS! Nice work!

Comment: @PavelReznikov: I take advantage of the situation as you are the author of gridtsak.js and ask you one more question: in this knockout example: http://troolee.github.io/gridstack.js/demo/knockout2.html, is it possible to load dynamic templates for different widgets? In that example there are 4 widgets. Can we specify for each widget a different template? Thanks!